# query sql database to echo highest auto incremented number

Tags: php, mysql, max

Im trying to make an sql function that displays the highest value however all the variations of the MAX function i use, still turn up with an empty image. What's going on here? how do i fix this?

//displays no image and doesn't give any errors

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM people") or die (mysql_error());
```

//displays image 87

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM people WHERE id = 87") or die (mysql_error());
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It shouldn't display an image, it should give a result of 87.

See [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)

You could do:

```
select * from people order by id desc limit 0, 1
```

which should give you the latest image by ID.

To make this dynamic and allow a next button you would need to store the value of image being viewed. When the next button is clicked you could then do

```
select * from people order by id desc limit 1, 1 //Start at row 1, bring back 1.
```

See [MySQL Limit](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

You would need to use PHP to assign the values in limit and your next link though. To do this you would need to have link like so:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/page?imagecount=1">Next</a>
```

Then using PHP you could:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["imagecount"]))
        $next = (int)$_GET["imagecount"]; //Don't forget the (int) cast to avoid SQL injection!!!
    else
        $next = 0;

   $result = mysql_query("select * from people order by id desc limit $next, 1") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

TO expand on the link, you could then make your link dynamic:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/page?imagecount=<?php echo $next+1; ?>">Next</a>
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks.

Comment: How would i get it to display the next value in the database with a next button!

Comment: I think it's LIMIT 1,1 for next value, not 1,2.

Comment: Must type fast to beat the person typing faster! :)

Comment: Well... I corrected before he posted... But I still got pointed at ^_^

Comment: Sorry guys would you mind elaborating... I want to make a button that will go to the next highest value on click. 
What would i have to do...
<?php

    $next = mysql_query("select * from people order by id desc limit 1, 1") or die...

<a href="<?php $next ?>">next image </a>
Sorry complete noob here!

Comment: Thanks so much!
....
weird, this is happening http://goawaymom.com/images.php?imagecount=84

next button doesn't go to next image....

Comment: It looks like you are spitting out the image ID into the link. That won't work with my example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20692/discussion-between-neat-and-webnoob)